# Protractor tests in Maven build with Jenkins

Tags: angularjs, maven, jenkins, protractor

I am currently trying to integrate protractor tests into a Jenkins build by putting it into the maven build that is being executed. As protractor isn't installed on the machine I am trying to test on, I've put this into my pom.xml:

```xml
    <execution>
        <id>run npm install protractor </id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
        <configuration>
            <arguments>install -g protractor</arguments>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
```

This produces the following output via Jenkins:

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (run npm install protractor) @ cpc-fe-impl ---
[INFO] Running 'npm install -g protractor' in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VF-CPC/cpc-fe/cpc-fe/cpc-fe-impl/angular
[WARNING] npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[INFO] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VF-CPC/cpc-fe/cpc-fe/cpc-fe-impl/target/bin/protractor -> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VF-CPC/cpc-fe/cpc-fe/cpc-fe-impl/target/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor
[INFO] /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VF-CPC/cpc-fe/cpc-fe/cpc-fe-impl/target/bin/webdriver-manager -> /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VF-CPC/cpc-fe/cpc-fe/cpc-fe-impl/target/lib/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager
[INFO] + protractor@7.0.0
[INFO] added 151 packages from 191 contributors in 8.082s
```

But when I try to execute the tests later in that same pom.xml with greengerong's maven-ng-protractor plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.greengerong</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ng-protractor</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <configFile>angular/e2e/protractor-jenkins.conf.js</configFile>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>ng-protractor</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

the protractor installation seems to be gone and the tests aren't executed

```
[INFO] --- maven-ng-protractor:0.0.2:run (ng-protractor) @ cpc-fe-impl ---
[INFO] protractor:protractor
[INFO] configFile:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VF-CPC/cpc-fe/cpc-fe/cpc-fe-impl/angular/e2e/protractor-jenkins.conf.js
[INFO] Executing protractor test Suite ...
[INFO] Command:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/VF-CPC/cpc-fe/cpc-fe/cpc-fe-impl/angular/e2e/protractor-jenkins.conf.js
[ERROR] Run protractor test error:
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "protractor": error=2, Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.github.greengerong.ProtractorService.exec (ProtractorService.java:34)
...
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? I have tried to run the protractor tests without maven by configuring the Jenkins build and executing my commands as a shell script, but protractor (and npm) can't be found there either.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by installing protractor globally through the NodeJS Plugin for Jenkins